# Connecting to a TCP port by using valid IP address

Tags: linux, networking, smtp, port, tcp

I have installed `Apache James` and I enabled smtp server on port 25. I can connect to port 25 inside the server by:

```
telnet localhost 25
```

but I cannot connect from outside of the server, by this command:

```
telnet validip 25
```

Inside the server I have this output for `netstat -a -n`:

```
tcp6       0      0 :::25                   :::*                    LISTEN
```

How can I connect to the smtp server on port 25 from outside of the server by using valid IP address?

PS: the port is allowed in firewall and it is opened in the network.

```
$ nmap validip
PORT    STATE  SERVICE
25/tcp  open   smtp
```

and inside the server:

```
# ufw status 
Status: active
To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
25/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
25                         ALLOW       Anywhere                  
25/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
25 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

Comment: One consideration: is validip an RFC 1918 address? If so, you'll need the source outside the network to be on the same subnet. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network

Comment: And if you're on a private network you'll need to configure port forwarding on the router.

Comment: Your ISP probably blocks outgoing connections to port 25. Try connecting from elsewhere.

Comment: Is this a residential network?

Answer (score 1):

Try connecting on IPv6 which should visible from the outside without requiring port forwarding.  IPv4 will likely require port forwarding to be configured on your router.

It you are intending on sending mail to servers you don't control, you should get a static IP address.  ISPs frequently block port 25 traffic on dynamic IPs to prevent spambots from working.

Try configuring your server to listen on port 587 (Submission).  This is less likely to be blocked, but may need to be forwarded on the router.

Seriously consider using a relay server for outgoing email.  Your ISP likely has one you can use.

Answer (score -1):

Try to connect locally using the ip address and not `localhost`.
Your netstat output suggests that your smtp server is not listening on ipV4, just on V6. Check your config (enabling V4) or make sure that you have full V6 connectivity and V6 enabled on the other hosts on your network.

Comment: Sorry, but a bind address of `:::25` doesn't mean ipv6 only - it usually means v4 and v6 both.